# Mutliple rows into a single row with comma-separated in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-concat

I have a question about Oracle: I want to combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited single rows.

```
create table emp ( empid varchar2 (100));

insert into emp values ('90322');
insert into emp values ('89333');
insert into emp values ('458999');
```

Based on above data I want output like below:

```
'90322', '89333', '458999'
```

I tried with this code:

```
select listagg(empid ,', ') within group(order by empid ) csv
from emp;
```

or

```
select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,empid,', ').extract('//text()') order by empid).getclobval(),', ') x
from emp;
```

It's working only for a few rows. If `emp` table have more than 5000 rows, then it's not working anymore and I'm getting an error:

> Error execution 1:1 ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task in Oracle.

Comment: the second statement should work(tried for 50k ID on DB version **12.2** and [**18**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec039b43c1e179bf973eedee65c10899) with success, while timeout occured for the version **11** on the same fiddle but gives no error)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user-defined aggregation function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CLOBAggregation AS OBJECT(
  value CLOB,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    value       IN     CLOB
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT CLOB,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY CLOBAggregation
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := CLOBAggregation( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    value       IN     CLOB
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := value;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value || ',' || value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    returnValue    OUT CLOB,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CLOBAggregation,
    ctx         IN OUT CLOBAggregation
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.value IS NULL THEN
      self.value := ctx.value;
    ELSIF ctx.value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      self.value := self.value || ',' || ctx.value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION CLOB_AGG( value CLOB )
RETURN CLOB
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING CLOBAggregation;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT CLOB_AGG(empid) csv
FROM   (
  SELECT empid
  FROM   emp
  ORDER BY empid
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=34d8d513f25dc0c260a748a272525b3e)*