# Generate JSON Structure looping over table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have ORACLE-SQL Table in below format.

Version is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

```
CREATE TABLE temp_Table 
   (
    "OVRPK_CNTNR_ID" CHAR(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ITEM_DISTB_Q" NUMBER(3) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "SSP_Q" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BRKPK_CNTNR_ID" CHAR(20)
    ) ;


INSERT INTO temp_Table (OVRPK_CNTNR_ID, ITEM_DISTB_Q, SSP_Q,  BRKPK_CNTNR_ID ) VALUES('92000000356873110552', 6,8,'93058901021076000085');
  INSERT INTO temp_Table (OVRPK_CNTNR_ID,ITEM_DISTB_Q,SSP_Q,   BRKPK_CNTNR_ID ) VALUES('92000000356873110552',8, 10,'93058901021117700080');
  INSERT INTO temp_Table (OVRPK_CNTNR_ID,ITEM_DISTB_Q,SSP_Q,   BRKPK_CNTNR_ID ) VALUES('92000000356873110552', 10,2,'93058901022276900083');
  INSERT INTO temp_Table (OVRPK_CNTNR_ID,ITEM_DISTB_Q,SSP_Q,   BRKPK_CNTNR_ID ) VALUES('92000000334160826089', 3,4,'000000000083465239'); 
  INSERT INTO temp_Table (OVRPK_CNTNR_ID,ITEM_DISTB_Q,SSP_Q,   BRKPK_CNTNR_ID ) VALUES('92000000334160826089', 3,4,'000000000083438160');
```

I have written trigger for above table.

```
AFTER INSERT OR  DELETE OR  UPDATE OF 
OVRPK_CNTNR_ID, ITEM_DISTB_Q, SSP_Q,  BRKPK_CNTNR_ID
ON 
temp_Table 
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
    json_message    CLOB := '';

BEGIN
    /*
     * pick OVRPK_CNTNR_ID from triggers row and send it to function createJson() return json object, example : 92000000356873110552
     */

    json_message = CALL FUNCTION createJson(:NEW.OVRPK_CNTNR_ID);

END;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createJson(ovrpk_container_id IN char)

BEGIN
SELECT json_query(
                    json_objectagg(OVRPK_CNTNR_ID value 
                                    json_array(
                                                json_object("break_pack_container_id" VALUE BRKPK_CNTNR_ID,
                                                            "ssp_quantity" VALUE SSP_Q,
                                                            "item_distribution_quantity" VALUE ITEM_DISTB_Q)))),
                                                            
                                                            
 '$' returning VARCHAR2(4000) pretty )
    AS "Result JSON" 
  FROM temp_Table
END;
```

I am trying to create OUTPUT like below: but oracle version is Database 12c. I am not sure if it supports.

```
{
  "Over_pack_container_id":"92000000356873110552"
  "type": "OVER_PACK",
  "sub_containers": [
    {
      "break_pack_container_id": "93058901021076000085",
      "ssp_quantity": 8,
      "item_distribution_quantity": 6
    },    
    {
      "break_pack_container_id": "93058901021117700080",
      "ssp_quantity": 10,
      "item_distribution_quantity": 8
    },
    {
      "break_pack_container_id": "93058901022276900083",
      "ssp_quantity": 2,
      "item_distribution_quantity": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

can someone help me here? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve with the trigger or the function because the trigger does not do anything.

However, you can get your JSON output format using:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'Over_pack_container_id' VALUE OVRPK_CNTNR_ID,
         KEY 'type' VALUE 'OVER_PACK',
         KEY 'sub_containers' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'break_pack_container_id' VALUE BRKPK_CNTNR_ID,
             KEY 'ssp_quantity' VALUE SSP_Q,
             KEY 'item_distribution_quantity' VALUE ITEM_DISTB_Q
           )
         )
       ) AS "Result JSON" 
FROM  temp_Table
GROUP BY OVRPK_CNTNR_ID;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| Result JSON |
| --- |
| {"Over_pack_container_id":"92000000334160826089","type":"OVER_PACK","sub_containers":[{"break_pack_container_id":"000000000083465239 ","ssp_quantity":4,"item_distribution_quantity":3},{"break_pack_container_id":"000000000083438160 ","ssp_quantity":4,"item_distribution_quantity":3}]} |
| {"Over_pack_container_id":"92000000356873110552","type":"OVER_PACK","sub_containers":[{"break_pack_container_id":"93058901021076000085","ssp_quantity":8,"item_distribution_quantity":6},{"break_pack_container_id":"93058901022276900083","ssp_quantity":2,"item_distribution_quantity":10},{"break_pack_container_id":"93058901021117700080","ssp_quantity":10,"item_distribution_quantity":8}]} |

If you only want a single container ID in your function then use a where clause:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'Over_pack_container_id' VALUE OVRPK_CNTNR_ID,
         KEY 'type' VALUE 'OVER_PACK',
         KEY 'sub_containers' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'break_pack_container_id' VALUE BRKPK_CNTNR_ID,
             KEY 'ssp_quantity' VALUE SSP_Q,
             KEY 'item_distribution_quantity' VALUE ITEM_DISTB_Q
           )
         )
       ) AS "Result JSON" 
FROM  temp_Table
WHERE OVRPK_CNTNR_ID = ovrpk_container_id
GROUP BY OVRPK_CNTNR_ID;
```

---

If you want to do it on a version before the JSON functions were introduced then you can use `LISTAGG` (from Oracle 11 and provided you are not generating more than 4000 byte strings):

```sql
SELECT '{'
       || '"Over_pack_container_id":"' || OVRPK_CNTNR_ID || '",'
       || '"type":"OVER_PACK",'
       || '"sub_containers":['
       || LISTAGG(
            '{'
            || '"break_pack_container_id":"' || BRKPK_CNTNR_ID || '"'
            || '"ssp_quantity":' || COALESCE(TO_CHAR(SSP_Q), 'null')
            || '"item_distribution_quantity":' || COALESCE(TO_CHAR(ITEM_DISTB_Q), 'null')
            || '}',
            ','
          ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BRKPK_CNTNR_ID)
       || ']'
       || '}'
       AS "Result JSON" 
FROM  temp_Table
GROUP BY OVRPK_CNTNR_ID;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q88d_qm6)

Comment: @MTO Thank you for answer, i am using oracle 12C. Does 12c supports these JSON APIs?

Comment: @user3534759 Try it and find out because the JSON support was introduced in (I think) Oracle 12.1 so it may depend on what minor version of Oracle 12 you are using.

Comment: @MTO unfortunately, it does not support. is it possible to concat key/values while looping temp_Table and form similar output structure?

Comment: @user3534759 That sounds complicated; just use string aggregation. (Updated)

Comment: @MTO this ans actually solved my problem. Thank you so much for help. accepted your answer

Comment: @MTO, you were correct, it can not store more than 4000 characters byte strings. Does using CLOB would solve this problem ?

Comment: @user3534759 You can use a CLOB but then you would need to aggregate the CLOBs. There are plenty of posts that give methods of aggregating CLOBs (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698138/mutliple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-comma-separated-in-oracle/68699526#68699526))