# Combine multiple BLOB to TAR-Archive

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, tar

I have several text files stored as CLOB in a table and want to export them together as an *.tar.gz file using PL/SQL.
The table looks for example like:

```
create table my_table(
  content  clob,
  filename varchar2(100))
```

The result is to be send via utl_http to a webservice therefore I don't have the oportunity to do this in a client.

Compressing and converting to BLOB is not the problem. Combine them in a way that is in a valid format makes me trouble.

I could not find any standard library and dont want to implement a tar algorithm.

Comment: Write a user-defined aggregation function to aggregate the CLOBs ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699526/1509264) gives an example of writing a UDF that you could adapt) and then use Java within the database to combine the files into an archive ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59250531/1509264) gives an example of reading from zips and you can probably adapt it to create zips).

Comment: You'd be better off not using PL/SQL. Write a tool outside the database that pulls the CLOB content, writes it to disk while piping through tar and gz. That could be done even with simplistic tools like SQLPlus if you configure its settings correctly and do a bit of shell cleanup of the output. Python and perl provide more robust options for getting the data, but the tar/gz piece leave for the OS to do.

Comment: Sory, I don't hava Java support for our database application.

Comment: Unfortunatly is the process, step where I only have PL/SQL, the best possible point in time to do that. 
Sending multiple uncompressed files is not recomend. 
Only alternative is to store the files as *.tar.gz in the first place.

Comment: If you don't have Java support then you are probably out of luck as PL/SQL does not really support archive formats and if you cannot use an embedded language that does (i.e. Java) then you will have to use something external to the database (as suggested by @PaulW)